# Why doesn't this add?

Tags: dart, for-loop, visual-studio-code

I've been having difficulty replicating a piece of code that runs in Pascal into dart. The program asks for the scores of two teams to be entered, added and the totals displayed in the end. I managed to get all inputs and outputs, but the addition within the for loop outputs 0 or null. Any advice?

```dart
import "dart:io";
import "dart:math";
import "dart:convert";

void main() {
  double pscore1 = 0;
  double Totscore1 = 0;

  print('Enter enter team 1 name');

  String? Team_one_Name = stdin.readLineSync();

  print('Enter enter team 2 name');
  String? Team_two_Name = stdin.readLineSync();

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print('Enter team 1 player score');

    double pscore1 = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
    double Totscore1 = (Totscore1 + pscore1);
  }

  print(' The total score is ${Totscore1}');
}
```

This is only for one score. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring new variables in your `for` loop instead of using the variables defined in your `main()` method. Since your new variables is named the same, they will "shadow" your other variables since Dart's scoping rules means that when we refer to something, we start searching from current scope and then get up one level at a time until we hit global scope:

Instead, try do the following:

```dart
import "dart:io";
import "dart:math";
import "dart:convert";

void main() {
  double pscore1 = 0;
  double totscore1 = 0;

  print('Enter enter team 1 name');
  String? Team_one_Name = stdin.readLineSync();

  print('Enter enter team 2 name');
  String? Team_two_Name = stdin.readLineSync();

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print('Enter team 1 player score');

    pscore1 = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
    totscore1 = totscore1 + pscore1;
  }

  print(' The total score is ${totscore1}');
}
```

(I renamed your `Totscore1` to `totscore1` since variables should NEVER start with a cased letter in Dart if we follow the normal naming conventions)